# Pattern Matches for Date Format: dd.MM.yyyy, MM.yyyy and yyyy

Tags: java, date

I need to check a date for a given string. The string that I get isn't regular and I don't want to use `Dateformat` or something like this. I'm trying to avoid getting multiple exceptions. I need a regex for`dd.MM.yyyy` and `MM.yyyy` and `yyyy`. At first I had

```
\\d+\\.?\\d+\\.?\\d+
```

but this isn't working.

Comment: why don't you want to use libraries made for this ? JodaTime for example is pretty good at this.

Comment: Since you want date, why not `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[[dd.]MM.]yyyy")`? that covers all three of your cases having optional pattern parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use a **regex**, here is a basic working example:

```java
String regex = "([0-9]{2}\\.){0,2}([0-9]{4})";
assert "03.2017".matches(regex);
assert "31.03.2017".matches(regex);
assert "2017".matches(regex);
assert !"23-2017".matches(regex);
```

Note that:

- it will only check that there are digits at the right place
- it won't detect incorrect years (for example `0013`) or incorrect days/months (day 45 or month 15)

To really check for dates, I suggest you use libraries especially made for this, like `DateFormat`, `JodaTime` or apache's `DateUtils`.

---

Using **DateTimeFormatter**:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[[dd.]MM.]yyyy");
// correct dates
assert formatter.parse("31.12.2017") != null;
assert formatter.parse("12.2017") != null;
assert formatter.parse("2017") != null;
// wrong date
assert formatter.parse("31.2017") == null;
```

---

Using **DateUtils** ([maven link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang)):

```java
String[] acceptedFormats = {"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"};

// correct dates
assert DateUtils.parseDate("07.12.2017", acceptedFormats) != null;
assert DateUtils.parseDate("07.2017", acceptedFormats) != null;
assert DateUtils.parseDate("2017", acceptedFormats) != null;
assert DateUtils.parseDate("2017", acceptedFormats) != null;
// wrong dates
assert DateUtils.parseDate("123.2012", acceptedFormats) == null;
assert DateUtils.parseDate("01.13.2012", acceptedFormats) == null;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This `matches(regex)` is sometimes like witchcraft for me

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the below

```
String regex = "([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})";
```

which will match the date dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: this covers only part of the question